# Maximum of $\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}{1-xy}$ over $[0,1] \times [0, 1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I wish to find the maximum of
$$\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}{1-xy}$$
over $[0,1] \times [0, 1]$, and where the maximum is achieved. I try to compute the gradient and set to zero, but this is not working out. Any help please?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is quite possible to find the maximum by finding the zero of the gradient. For that reason, it'd be helpful if you could include that information within the problem statement so we can ascertain your progress.

Comment: Setting the gradient to $0$ only helps you locate maximizer inside. Don't forget to locate the maximizer on the boundary.

Comment: @Nameless: Quite so, though in this case the gradient vanishes on the boundary as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make the following substitution: $u = \sqrt{xy}$, $v = x+y$.

Then, $\dfrac{x(1-x)y(1-y)}{1-xy} = \dfrac{xy(1-x-y+xy)}{1-xy} = \dfrac{u^2(1-v+u^2)}{1-u^2} = : g(u,v)$.

Also, the allowable range for $u,v$ is $0 \le u \le 1$ and $2u \le v \le 1+u^2$.

For any fixed $u$, it is clear that $g(u,v)$ is decreasing in $v$, so the maximum will occur for the smallest possible value of $v$, that is $v = 2u$.

Then, $g(u,2u) = \dfrac{u^2(1-2u+u^2)}{1-u^2} = \dfrac{u^2(1-u)^2}{(1-u)(1+u)} = \dfrac{u^2(1-u)}{1+u} =: h(u)$.

To maximize $h(u)$, take the derivative, set it equal to $0$, and solve. (Also check endpoints).

$h'(u) = \dfrac{(1+u)\cdot(2u-3u^2)-(u^2-u^3)\cdot 1}{(1+u)^2} = \dfrac{2u-2u^2-2u^3}{(1+u)^2} = \dfrac{2u(1-u-u^2)}{(1+u)^2} = 0$

$u = 0$ or $1-u-u^2 = 0 \leadsto u = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

By testing $u = 0$, $u = 1$, and $u = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, we find that the maximum occurs for $u = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Now, you can plug this in to $h(u)$ to get the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

From

> http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/multivariable/maxima_minima.html

Let
$$D = f_{xx}(a, b)*f_{yy}(a,b) - (f_{xy}(a,b))^2$$

- If If $D > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) > 0$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $(a,b)$.
- If $D > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) < 0$, then $f$ has a relative maximum at $(a,b)$.
- If $D < 0$, then $f$ has a saddle point at $(a,b)$.
- If $D = 0$, then no conclusion can be drawn.